# asp.net identity doesnt work with jwt bearer token

Tags: jwt, asp.net-identity, token, asp.net-core-6.0

I created a solution with one web app that has asp.net core 6 with identity individual accounts and one web API. I added jwt tokens for the API and everything worked as it should. Now I have been told do delete the API and just add controllers in the webapp instead. I copied all the jwt files to the web app and now the asp.net identity doesnt work as it should. I can log in but as soon as the page is redirected to the homepage it says Im not logged in.

This is what I added to the program.cs file and as soon as I delete it everything works as it should.
`builder.Services.AddJWTTokenServices(builder.Configuration);`

This is my extensions

```
 public static class AddJWTTokenServiceExtension
    {
        public static void AddJWTTokenServices(this IServiceCollection Services, IConfiguration Configuration)
        {
            // Add Jwt Setings
            var bindJwtSettings = new JwtSettings();
            Configuration.Bind("JsonWebTokenKeys", bindJwtSettings);
            Services.AddSingleton(bindJwtSettings);
            Services.AddAuthentication(options => {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(options => {
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = bindJwtSettings.ValidateIssuerSigningKey,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bindJwtSettings.IssuerSigningKey)),
                    ValidateIssuer = bindJwtSettings.ValidateIssuer,
                    ValidIssuer = bindJwtSettings.ValidIssuer,
                    ValidateAudience = bindJwtSettings.ValidateAudience,
                    ValidAudience = bindJwtSettings.ValidAudience,
                    RequireExpirationTime = bindJwtSettings.RequireExpirationTime,
                    ValidateLifetime = bindJwtSettings.RequireExpirationTime,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
                };
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

> I can log in but as soon as the page is redirected to the homepage it
> says Im not logged in.

After you configure Jwt in the project, The default authentication method has become `Jwt` instead of `identity individual accounts`.
Actually when you log in, you have loged in (`you can check the cookie`), But because the defualt authentication method is `Jwt`, `SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User)` can't get any information about `User`, So it will not show like `Hello xxxx`.

```
options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
```

The above code shows jwt as the default authentication method, you just need to remove them.